# assign text file value to dynamically created jTextFields

Tags: java, swing

I have `jPanel1` with `jTextField1` and `addTfButton`. `addTfButton` adding dynamic `tf` to `jPanel2`. 
Using this code I want to load text file data to `jTextField1` and dynamically created `tf`:

```
private void loadButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {   
    try {
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader ("file.txt"));
          String str=null;

          while( (str = br.readLine()) !=null ) {
              String[] s = str.split(":");                   
              jTextField2.setText(s[2]);

              for (int i = 0; i < jPanel2.getComponentCount(); i++) {
                  SubPanel panel = (SubPanel) jPanel2.getComponent(i);
                    JTextField tf = panel.getTf();
                    tf.setText(s[2]);
                    System.out.println(s[2]);
              }
           }
     }
```

Mu SubPanel class:

```
private class SubPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {        
        SubPanel me;
        JTextField tf = new JTextField();        
    public SubPanel() {
            super();
            me = this;                      
            me.setLayout(new javax.swing.BoxLayout(me, javax.swing.BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));          
            tf.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 16));
            me.add(tf);          
    } 

    public JTextField getTf(){
            return tf;
    }
}
```

The contents of `file.txt`:

```
Name:1:a
Name:2:b
Name:3:c
```

To dynamic `jTextfields` I want to load values: `b, c`. 
But with above code dynamically added `tf` reading just `s[2]` of end row, i.e. `c`:

```
a //jTextField2
c //dynamically created tf[1]
c //dynamically created tf[2]
```

I w'd like to ask how to assign `s[2]` value to dynamically created `jTextFields`?

Comment: Did you get those output values (a, c, c) from debugging or from the `System.out.println()`? Because it seems it should work and I do not see a reason why it should have the same reference. I would double check if I really get those values for each lien by debugging.

Comment: @JernejK from debugging, I don't know why same reference maybe I am missing something.

Comment: If you get the same by debugging, I would take a look at the `str` value from `str.split(":");`. I would debug this value to verify I get the lines Name:1:a, Name:1:b, Name:1:c

Comment: I know your problem now. It is like someone wrote in the solution.

Comment: I have added code of `SubPanel`

Comment: So you are definitely overriding the value, because you have a for loop inside the while loop. So every time you go to another iteration (read a new line), you go with a for loop through all the sub panels you have and assign them the value `s[2]`. I hope you know what I mean. If I understand you correctly, you want to have each value you read in a separate sub panel, right?

Comment: yes I am storing them in separate sub panel. The values `b` and `c` were retrieved from dynamic `tf` by `saveButton`.

Comment: This means it does not make sense you iterate through EVERY `SubPanel` for every line you read. And how many `SubPanel` instances does jPanel2 have? Is the number the same size as the number of rows.

Comment: I see the situation. If user add 9 `tf`, it will output 9 name to text file. So what do you suggest to solve it?

Comment: I wrote a solution down. First do that change, then we can go further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set each value you read separately, then you would have to take the for loop out of the while loop.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader ("file.txt"));
String str=null;
// I set the counter to zero
int i = 0;
while( (str = br.readLine()) !=null ) {

    String[] s = str.split(":");                   
    jTextField2.setText(s[2]);

    SubPanel panel = (SubPanel) jPanel2.getComponent(i);
    JTextField tf = panel.getTf();
    tf.setText(s[2]);
    System.out.println(s[2]);
    // for each new line we take the next SubPanel
    i++;
}
```

This would allow you to set each value you read in a separate `SubPanel`. First try that, then we can go from there.

**UPDATE**

From what you told me, you would like to save the first value in the `jTexField2` instance and the rest of the values in the `tf` instances of each `SubPanel`. Then my solution would be the following:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader ("file.txt"));
String str=null;
// I set the counter to zero
int i = 0;
while( (str = br.readLine()) !=null ) {

    String[] s = str.split(":");
    if(i == 0) {
        // First line of every file would be added to the TextField2 instance                
        jTextField2.setText(s[2]);

    } else {
        // Every additional line would be added to the tf instance
        // we have to substract -1 to i in order to get the first SubPanel
        SubPanel panel = (SubPanel) jPanel2.getComponent(i - 1);
        JTextField tf = panel.getTf();
        tf.setText(s[2]);
    }
    System.out.println(s[2]);
    // for each new line we take the next SubPanel
    i++;
}
```

Comment: sorry, I was mistake with `jPanel`, the output: jTextField2: c, tf[0]: a, tf[1]: b, tf[2]: c

Comment: As you can see the jTextField sets the text for each line. Same as before for the dynamic field. But now it works like you want? If you do not want that, then just add for example a if statement. That way you can set the first vale with if(i ==0) { jTextField2.setText() }

Comment: if statement works for `jTextField2`, then I w'd like to ask how can I set for `tf[0]: b, tf[1]: c`?

Comment: So that I understand you, you would like to store `a` in jTextField2, and the rest (b and c) in those `TextField` instances of SubPanel? I just wnat to double check and then I can write you the code.

Comment: OK, I will update the logic in my answer. Just give me a minute.

Comment: Done. The Update area has now the logic you want. Take a look @hub

Comment: And if you are satisfied, then mark the question as answered @hub

Comment: you are G.R.E.A.T (Grateful, Respect, Effulgent, Action, Thanks)!! You made my day! I am very grateful for your effort. Hvala!!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like second and third SubPanel are containing the same JTextField object. But I haven't seen entire code.

Comment: I think this is exactly the problem. He uses the for loop and iterates through all the components inside the while loop. That way he overrides all the values. You can double check by debugging and looking up values, before you set the last value c.

Comment: Also we need code for creating jPanel2, where SubPanels are added.